# How to expand a wordpress shortcode within pre tags?

Tags: wordpress

I want to use wordpress shortcodes within pre tags, e.g.

```
<pre>
  [somepluginshortcode id=89]
</pre>
```

Where the shortcode returns some text.

By default, it seems that shortcodes are not 'executed' within pre tags.

Not sure how to get around that. Is it possible??

Comment: Can't you use the pre tags *inside* the shortcode?

Comment: The somepluginshortcode shortcode is development for you or used by you...

Comment: `function my_shortcode() { return '<pre>' . $my_content . '</pre>'; }`

Comment: Used by me, written by someone else. What I want is to have code snippets in separate posts, and be able to include them, as syntax highlighted code in other posts.

Comment: Thanks brasofilo. I have no idea what to do with that function??